# javascript seprated comma values

Tags: javascript

My output is: `abcdefghj`.

Expected output is: `abc,cdf,fgh`

```js
function spanvalue() {
  var node = document.querySelector('.keywords-list').textContent;
  alert(node);
  var input = document.querySelector('.hidden');
  input.value = node;
}
```

```html
<div class="keywords-list">
  <div class ="keywords-list">
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>one</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>two</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>three</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>four</span></div>
  </div>                          
</div>
```

Comment: Please clearly separate your JavaScript code from the relevant HTML portion.

Comment: Not sure why you expect commas in there. And you have to ask a question so we know what you're having trouble with

Comment: your output is "abcdefghj"?  How? There is nothing in the code you have posted that would cause that output.

Comment: @Kyle it alerts

Comment: I see an alert - but where do you see anything that would produce: "abcdefghj" unless that's just the format they are looking for.

Comment: @Kyle Hahaha, I didn't even notice, the spans say `one, two, three`, not `abc, def` :p

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that's going to insert those commas for you.

I assume you have only one `keyword_list` div (not two with one nested inside the other). If you want to get the text of the spans within it separated by commas, get the text of the spans as an array and then join them together with commas:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.keywords-list span');
var str = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(node) {
    return node.textContent;
}).join(",");
```

```js
function spanvalue() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.keywords-list span');
    var str = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(node) {
        return node.textContent;
    }).join(",");
    console.log(str);
}
spanvalue();
```

```html
<div class="keywords-list">
<div><input value="somevalue" /><span>one</span></div>
<div><input value="somevalue" /><span>two</span></div>
<div><input value="somevalue" /><span>three</span></div>
<div><input value="somevalue" /><span>four</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Take the result of `node` then `split()` on non-word characters with RegExp (`\W` for non-word characters)
- Remove empty array items as a result of the `split()` using `filter()`
- Convert the Array to a comma-separated String with `join()`

Refactor the function to below in the JS section which is:

- Add `var output = node.split(/\W/).filter(a => !!a).join(',');` after declaring `node`
- Refactor to set `input.value` as `output`

```js
function spanvalue() {
  var node = document.querySelector('.keywords-list').textContent;
  var output = node.split(/\W/).filter(a => !!a).join(',');
  // alert(node);
  var input = document.querySelector('.hidden');
  input.value = output;
}

spanvalue();
```

```html
 <div class="keywords-list">
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>one</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>two</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>three</span></div>
    <div><input value="somevalue"/><span>four</span></div>
</div>
<div>Output: <input class="hidden"></div>
```